# TypeError: sum() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given). Confused with my error?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, error-handling

Not sure why I am receiving a TypeError: sum() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given). Is my code correct?

Investigate the distribution of weight for different age groups. To start, partition the dataset into three DataFrames by filtering df and assign them to the following variables:
df_20s: Only the rows where 'age' is less than 30
df_30s: Only the rows where 'age' is greater than or equal to 30 and less than 40
df_40s: Only the rows where 'age' is greater than or equal to 40 (includes age 50)
To verify that you filtered correctly, print the following results:
The sum of the lengths of the three DataFrames (there should be 10,000 rows total)
The min and max value in the 'age' column of df_20s
The min and max value in the 'age' column of df_30s
The min and max value in the 'age' column of df_40s
The precode already contains a template for you to print your results; just finish the code.

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('/datasets/height_weight.csv')

df_20s = (df[df['age'] < 30])
df_30s = (df[(df['age'] >= 30) & (df['age'] < 40)])
df_40s = (df[df['age'] >= 40])


# print out the results
print("Sum of data frame lengths:",sum(len(df_20s),len(df_30s),len(df_40s)))
print("Min and max age for df_20s:", df_20s['age'].min(), df_20s['age'].max() )
print("Min and max age for df_30s:", df_30s['age'].min(), df_30s['age'].max() )
print("Min and max age for df_40s:", df_40s['age'].min(), df_40s['age'].max() )
```

Traceback:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [1], in <cell line: 13>()
      9 df_40s [38;5;241m=[39m (df[df[[38;5;124m'[39m[38;5;124mage[39m[38;5;124m'[39m] [38;5;241m>[39m[38;5;241m=[39m [38;5;241m40[39m])
     12 [38;5;66;03m# print out the results[39;00m
---> 13 [38;5;28mprint[39m([38;5;124m"[39m[38;5;124mSum of data frame lengths:[39m[38;5;124m"[39m,[38;5;28;43msum[39;49m[43m([49m[38;5;28;43mlen[39;49m[43m([49m[43mdf_20s[49m[43m)[49m[43m,[49m[38;5;28;43mlen[39;49m[43m([49m[43mdf_30s[49m[43m)[49m[43m,[49m[38;5;28;43mlen[39;49m[43m([49m[43mdf_40s[49m[43m)[49m[43m)[49m)
     14 [38;5;28mprint[39m([38;5;124m"[39m[38;5;124mMin and max age for df_20s:[39m[38;5;124m"[39m, df_20s[[38;5;124m'[39m[38;5;124mage[39m[38;5;124m'[39m][38;5;241m.[39mmin(), df_20s[[38;5;124m'[39m[38;5;124mage[39m[38;5;124m'[39m][38;5;241m.[39mmax() )
     15 [38;5;28mprint[39m([38;5;124m"[39m[38;5;124mMin and max age for df_30s:[39m[38;5;124m"[39m, df_30s[[38;5;124m'[39m[38;5;124mage[39m[38;5;124m'[39m][38;5;241m.[39mmin(), df_30s[[38;5;124m'[39m[38;5;124mage[39m[38;5;124m'[39m][38;5;241m.[39mmax() )
TypeError: sum() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `sum(len(df_20s),len(df_30s),len(df_40s)))`, use:

```
sum([len(df_20s),len(df_30s),len(df_40s))])
```

You can also improve your code to use a dictionary and loop:

```
d = {'df_20s' : (df[df['age'] < 30]),
     'df_30s' : (df[(df['age'] >= 30) & (df['age'] < 40)]),
     'df_40s' : (df[df['age'] >= 40])
    }


# print out the results
print("Sum of data frame lengths:", sum(map(len, d.values()))
for k, v in d.items():
    print(f"Min and max age for {k}: {v['age'].min()}, {v['age'].max()}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution here is to use a tuple containing the values instead of a list:

```py
sum((len(df_20s),len(df_30s),len(df_40s))))
```

By enclosing the values in parentheses and passing it as a tuple to the sum() function, the function will correctly calculate the sum of the values.